# Convertir de grid a array

Tags: c#, array, windows-forms, gridview

Tengo un `dataGridView1` con 3 **columnas nombre, cantidad y precio** necesito llevarlas al siguiente formato

```
000000010000001000Papas
```

donde:

> (0000000100)(00001000)(Papas)

El primero es el precio, el segundo la cantidad y el tercero el nombre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No lo he probado, pero creo que algo así podria funcionar:

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string datos = "";
            foreach (DataGridViewCell item2 in item.Cells)
            {
                datos += item2.Value.ToString();
            }
            //y aqui ya haces lo que quieras con el string
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar así (no he probado el código):

```
string resultado = string.Empty;
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    resultado += "(" + item["nombre"].text + item["cantidad"].text + item["precio"].text + ")";
}
```